# Inject variables only in teasers (template suggestions)

Tags: theming

How could I detect if node type is article (in template.php) but process variables only for teaser of article, not article i full mode. (I have template suggestions so i have node--article-teaser.tpl.php). Like:

```
if ($node->type == 'article' and inject only if article-teaser.tpl.php)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a preprocess/process function for the node template file, you just need to check the following variables:

- `$variables['teaser']` must be `TRUE`
- `$variables['node']->type` must be `'article'`

`$variables` is the parameter passed to preprocess/process functions.